# Is there an auto-resizing array/dynamic array implementation for C that comes with glibc?

Tags: c, data-structures, glibc

Is there a [dynamic array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_list) implementation in glibc or any of the standard Linux libraries for C?  I want to be able to add to a list without worrying about its size.  I know std::vector exists for C++, but I need the C equivalent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess you are thinking of [realloc](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/realloc.html). But its better to wrap a *list* in a structure to keep track of its current length

Example API

```
struct s_dynamic_array {
    int allocated;   /* keep track of allocated size  */
    int usedLength;  /* keep track of usage           */
    int *array;      /* dynamicaly grown with realloc */
};
typedef struct s_dynamic_array s_dynamic_array;

s_dynamic_array *new_dynamic_array(int initalSize);
void             free_dynamic_array(s_dynamic_array *array);
int              size_of_dynamic_array(s_dynamic_array *array);
s_dynamic_array *add_int_to_dynamic_array(s_dynamic_array *array, int value);
int              int_at_index(s_dynamic_array *array, int index);
```

Comment: Dang.  Full implementation too.  Thanks a lot epatel.

Answer (score 4):

There is a dynamic array in glib. (not glibc though) Check out GArray and GPtrArray. A dynamic array is not really the same thing as a linked list though.

Anyways [this](http://www.scribd.com/doc/3499572/Manage-C-Data-Using-the-GLib-Collections) is the most useful resource I've been able to find when learning glib.

Answer (score 1):

I always use [realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc.html) for this, you could wrap your own array functions around it. AFAIK, there are no other built-in things for this.

Comment: i was hoping to avoid re-inventing the wheel.  what a shame.  I'm sure the wrappering you're talking about happens all the time.

Comment: :-)  Alright.  I'll use realloc.  Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: No problem, that's what SO is for :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [obstacks](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Obstacks.html#Obstacks)